# Visible the table

Tags: php

My Output for this php is the table in database is retrieved in table of the page. Now , I would like to make the table in page become visible when click this php in browser, when i enter the name in text box, it will retrived the name with row. All I success, only the table visible havent done. Below is my code and the output i would like when open the php:

Now my output when open this php is the output i post below but got information in table. Now I would like make them become visible when I open this php and when i enter the name in text box and click search button, the row of table will display if it is match with name.

Php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
// search in all table columns
// using concat mysql function
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, 
`username`, `name`, `date`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wp");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>REWARD DATA SEARCH</title>
    <style>
        table,tr,th,td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Enter Name"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"><br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>

  <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Output I would like to do when open the php:

[image]

Comment: if i understand correctly, you want an empty table on initial load? just take out your `else` block so that it doesn't fetch the `select *`

Comment: ok, now i try it

Comment: didn't understand the question properly can u please give more explanation what exactly you need?

Comment: @Prateik just like what Ghost say

Comment: @Ghost i try it , it is ok, but it come out notice and warning

Comment: @MollyMolly one band aid solution is just to add `LIMIT 0` on the `else` query, it wont show anything, a proper solution would be to initialize a container up top, then when submitted fetch the rows it inside it, then you would replace the `while` below with `foreach`

Comment: @Ghost, thanks, after add LIMIT 0, it is work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
        </tr>
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

after this just place code

```
 <?php if(empty($search_result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan = '4' align='center'>Data not found.</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This will load initial table with no data.

Comment: but when i enter name in text box, but the result will not displayed in row.

Comment: it will print the table with data not found. you need table when data not found or need to hide the table when data not found what you want?

Comment: The data actually got stored in database, what i want is initially the table is empty with data, when user enter the information in text box, for my case, my user will enter name stored in database, after click search button, it will display the row with the name user key in the text box, hope can understand my question and sorry for my bad english

Comment: no, i really don't understand still, what you want as output. because as per your query it says that on initial load it will display all the data from the database table and whenever there will be some search then it will display output matches with your search query. it should work as it displays, what errors you facing?

Comment: like this example http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.my/2015/10/php-html-table-search-filter-data-mysql-database.html  but no same is its initial got display table with information but my one is initial the information in table are not display, and when user search, it will display

Comment: are you able to run query in mysql itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160482/discussion-between-prateik-and-molly-molly).